# How do I get an old account I no longer have access to deleted?

Tags: discussion, support, duplicate-accounts

When I first discovered Stack Overflow, I signed up just to ask a question; I believe at the time it didn't require making an account, just had to enter my name. I found it because I Googled my name, and it came up in the Google search.

**Is there any way to get this account deleted?**

There are no questions/answers, and since I don't use it it hasn't been logged in to since it was created. There is also a Stack Exchange account with the same name I would like to be deleted so it doesn't come up in search results, again it has nothing on it.

Comment: Another option might be to *merge* those accounts into your current account.

Comment: @TRiG I can't do anything with them because I have no way to access them. If I did use an email to create them I no longer have access to that either

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> There are no questions/answers

It will get deleted in time then. Users/accounts that have made no contributions get deleted after a year.

If that's not enough - you will need to use the [contact us](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) form to involve Stack Exchange staff to do this for you. However - you will need to provide some proof of ownership (though, if you point out that the account/user has made no contributions and has been dormant for a while, that might not be needed).

Comment: It's from 2013, why hasn't it been deleted yet?

Comment: Did you use Facebook authorization?

Comment: @Shadow - why? It likely made more contributions than you think/remember. I suggest emailing [the team](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) with details (links) to the profile/s - they can confirm why. But if it wasn't deleted already, they will likely need proof from you.